# save numpy array to csv column start as same point

Tags: python, csv, numpy, save, text-styling

I have array of numpy and I need to save it to csv file.
I want to get nice display as in the picture below when I open it using notepad
I want all the column to start at same position, like the [2,5] and [4] are
I cant figure out how to set the dynamic padding between columns

Thanks alot Alon
[image]

Comment: Use tab as a delimiter? You haven't given an upper bound on how long those arrays might be, so it's not easy to suggest a solution.

Comment: Smells alot like homework... Also, we have no idea what your data looks like, and you've made no attempt at beginning to solve this

Comment: I have only 3 columns and I cant have any assumptions about their length. I tried to use tab as delimiter but It did not changed the space between the columns dynamicly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use xlsx format for that using pandas library in python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating a dataframe and saving as test.csv in current directory
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100000, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
df.to_csv('test.csv', index = False)

# Reading in test.csv and saving as test.xlsx

df_new = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx')
df_new.to_excel(writer, index = False)
writer.save()
```